# UIScrollView with dynamic buttons doesn't scroll

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview

I have an UIScrollview with dynamic buttons in it,scroll only works when touch is in scrollview. When touch is in button, it doesn't scroll.

Give me a solution.

Comment: Please add your code, and elaborate your problem. Seeing code will help to understand the problem better.

Answer (score 1):

UIScrollView has property `delaysContentTouches` which default to YES, so if you drag your finger fast enough button won't get touch event. I guess you just need to move your finger quicker to move the scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Simple check this points:

- Make sure you have assign delegate to self to scroll view & defined UIScrollViewDelegate in .h file
- Make sure paging enabled to yes like this:

> yourScrollView.pagingEnabled = true;

- Now simply put this line on button click event:

> [scrollview setContentOffset:CGPointMake(scrollview.contentOffset.x +
>   self.view.frame.size.width,scrollview.contentOffset.y) animated:YES];

I found in few device with specific IOS it not works so in this case add 1 more line like this:

```
[self scrollViewDidScroll: yourScrollView];
```

Comment: Sorry to say, but this answer is vague and incomplete. What is `winSize` here? Why should the user set `pagingEnabled`? Please, add relevant information/explanation to your answers, so that other users can understand them easily.

Comment: @n00bProgrammer its just for an example not actual :)
Still if you can refresh & see i have changed it with more understandable format